# How to do Interpolation to this function after given b this values

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, list-manipulation, interpolation, subscript

```
  χ[b_] := (Z/k)*NIntegrate[Subscript[f, pp1][q]*Subscript[F, pp1][q]*BesselJ[0, q*b]*q, {q, 0, b}]; 

  bList = Table[b, {b, 0, 5.1 , 0.05}]
```

where:

```
     Z = 6;
     k=1.55246;
```

```
     Subscript[f, pp1][q_]=(6.254736279890945*(1 - 1.4511668475476842))/E^(0.2115*q^2)

     Subscript[F, pp1][q_] := ((4*Pi)/q)*NIntegrate[Subscript[ρ, p][r]*Sin[q*r]*r, {r, 0, Infinity}]; 

     Subscript[ρ, p][r_]=0.013132593248303927/(1 + (E^(1.7543859649122808*(-2.380427976610103 - r)) + E^(1.7543859649122808*(-2.380427976610103 + r)))*
    (0.5 + 0.08823886490842314*r^2)^1.5)
```

Comment: Please provide values for all the constants and definitions of the functions or we can't answer this.

Comment: The definition of `Subscript[f, pp1]` is missing the argument and should presumably read `Subscript[f, pp1][q_]` and the definition contains an undefined variable `i`

Comment: I fix it, Please help me in the error

Comment: I think to do interpolation here , because the program said ,((NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand (0.0131326 r Sin[q r])/(1+(E^(1.75439 Plus[<<2>>])+E^(1.75439 Plus[<<2>>])) (0.5 +0.0882389 Power[<<2>>])^1.5) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{\[Infinity],0.}}.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Subscript[f, pp1][q_] = (6.254736279890945*(1 - 1.4511668475476842))/
   E^(0.2115*q^2);

Subscript[F, pp1][q_?NumericQ] := ((4*Pi)/q)*
   NIntegrate[Subscript[ρ, p][r]*Sin[q*r]*r, {r, 0, Infinity}];

Subscript[ρ, p][r_] = 
  0.013132593248303927/(1 + \
(E^(1.7543859649122808*(-2.380427976610103 - r)) + 
        E^(1.7543859649122808*(-2.380427976610103 + r)))*(0.5 + 
         0.08823886490842314*r^2)^1.5);

χ[b_?NumericQ] := (Z/k)*NIntegrate[
    Subscript[f, pp1][q]*Subscript[F, pp1][q]*BesselJ[0, q*b]*q, {q, 0, b}];

Z = 6; k = 1.55246;

data = {#, χ[#]} & /@ Range[0, 5.1, 0.05] // Quiet;

f = Interpolation[data];

Plot[f[b], {b, 0, 5.1}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[3], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: what I can do Please, I did like your answer but I am waiting the program 7 hours until now running (( f = Interpolation[data];))

Comment: @Alshammari - I just reran the code on my laptop using version 12.1.1. `AbsoluteTiming` for calculation of `data` took `59.9884` seconds and calculation of `f` took `0.000592` seconds. If you copied the above and executed it, the problem must be due to a version difference.

Comment: @Alshammari and @BobHanlon, since `Subscript[F, pp1][q_?NumericQ] ` is called very often, generate an InterpolatingFunction of it, here F1, and use it with chi.  `Subscript[F1, pp1] = 
  FunctionInterpolation[Subscript[F, pp1][q], {q, .01, 5.1}]; ` This is much faster (although problems at very small q with NIntegrate have to be solved).